# site2site wireguard with docker : routing problems

Tags: vpn, docker, containers, wireguard, routes

Disclaimer: repost from stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917278/site2site-wireguard-with-docker-routing-problems

I am trying to have two containers, running on two RPI, act as a site-to-site VPN between Network 1 and Network 2.

With the setup below, I am able to ping *from within the container* each other network:

- from docker container 1 I can ping an address 192.168.1.1
- from docker container 2 I can ping the address 192.168.10.1

But if I try to ping 192.168.1.1 from the System1 host (192.168.10.100) I have errors (see below image to visualize what I am trying to do).

I understand I have to add a static route on system1 host (192.168.10.100) to direct the traffic for 192.168.1.0/24 through the wireguard container (172.17.0.5), thus I run:

```
$i p route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 172.17.0.5
$ ip route
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.10.100 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-e19a4f1b7646 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-19684dacea29 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-446863cf7cef proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-6800ed9b4dd6 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-8f8f439a7a28 proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 via 172.17.0.5 dev docker0 
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.100 
192.168.10.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.100 metric 100
```

but the ping to 192.168.1.1 still fails.

by running tcpdump on the container 2 I see that some packets are indeed reaching the container :

```
root@936de7c0d7eb:/# tcpdump -n -i any
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
10:11:19.885845 IP [publicIPsystem1].56200 > 172.17.0.6.56100: UDP, length 128
10:11:30.440764 IP 172.17.0.6.56100 > [publicIPsystem1].56200: UDP, length 32
10:11:35.480625 ARP, Request who-has 172.17.0.1 tell 172.17.0.6, length 28
10:11:35.480755 ARP, Reply 172.17.0.1 is-at 02:42:24:e5:ac:38, length 28
```

so I guess it is not a routing problem on system 1.

Can anyone tell me how to diagnose this further?

---

**EDIT 1:**
I have done the following test:

1. run 'tcpdump -ni any' on container 2
2. sent a ping from System 1 (from the host system) 'ping -c 1 192.168.1.1 .
   On container 2 tcpdump records the following:

```
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
    15:04:47.495066 IP [publicIPsystem1].56200 > 172.17.0.3.56100: UDP, length 128
    15:04:58.120761 IP 172.17.0.3.56100 > [publicIPsystem1].56200: UDP, length 32
```

3. sent a ping from container (within the container) 'ping -c 1 192.168.1.1 .
   On container 2 tcpdump records the following:

```
# tcpdump -ni any
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
15:05:48.120717 IP [publicIPsystem1].56200 > 172.17.0.3.56100: UDP, length 128
15:05:48.120871 IP 10.13.18.2 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 747, seq 1, length 64
15:05:48.120963 IP 172.17.0.3 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 747, seq 1, length 64
15:05:48.121955 IP 192.168.1.1 > 172.17.0.3: ICMP echo reply, id 747, seq 1, length 64
15:05:48.122054 IP 192.168.1.1 > 10.13.18.2: ICMP echo reply, id 747, seq 1, length 64
15:05:48.122246 IP 172.17.0.3.56100 > [publicIPsystem1].56200: UDP, length 128
15:05:53.160617 ARP, Request who-has 172.17.0.1 tell 172.17.0.3, length 28
15:05:53.160636 ARP, Request who-has 172.17.0.3 tell 172.17.0.1, length 28
15:05:53.160745 ARP, Reply 172.17.0.3 is-at 02:42:ac:11:00:03, length 28
15:05:53.160738 ARP, Reply 172.17.0.1 is-at 02:42:24:e5:ac:38, length 28
15:05:58.672032 IP [publicIPsystem1].56200 > 172.17.0.3.56100: UDP, length 32
```

so, It seems that packets are treated differently from container 2 depending on something that I am currently missing.. **could it be an iptables problem?**

---

[image]

|  | Site 1 | Site 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Network 1 IP range | 192.168.10.0/24 | 192.168.1.0/24 |
| host system address | 192.168.10.100 | 192.168.1.100 |
| bridge docker0 range | 172.17.0.0/16 | 172.17.0.0/16 |
| container address | 172.17.0.5 | 172.17.0.6 |

System 1 - wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.18.2
PrivateKey = *privatekey*
ListenPort = 56200
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = *publickey*
Endpoint = *system2address*:56100
AllowedIPs = 10.13.18.1/32 , 192.168.1.0/24
```

System 2 - wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.18.1
ListenPort = 56100
PrivateKey = *privatekey*
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
# peer_casaleuven
PublicKey = *publickey*
AllowedIPs = 10.13.18.2/32 , 192.168.10.0/24
Endpoint = *system1address*:56200
```

Comment: When you ping 192.168.1.1 from the system 1 - do you see packets arriving at container 1 and leaving it that you could correlate to the inbound packets you see on the container 2 (cause what you see can be just keepalives or something)? Does WireGuard have any logs that you can look at? What does the routing table on container 1 looks like?

Comment: yes I have tried to run 'tcpdump -ni any' on both containers at the same time, waited for a couple of seconds to verify that no other packets were recorded. Then I run 'ping -c 1 192.168.1.1' to send just one ping from system 1 and I see the packets passing in both tcpdumps.

Comment: added another test in the Edit 1 section

Comment: note: I hope container's `eth0` is unrelated, because there should be no NAT anywhere. So I don't understand why this rule exist: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` within `PostUp`

Comment: the rule iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE was put by default by the linuxserver/wireguard in the initial configuration. If I remove them from both PostUp and PostDown in both container, then I am not able to ping anything anymore.

Comment: Ok. Anyway this doesn't change anything to the answer I wrote below. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it works!!! Thank you so much! I wonder though why that roule is so foundamental to make it work. If I run iptables --list I don't see any NAT table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a routing issue.

> `192.168.1.0/24 via 172.17.0.5 dev docker0`

This route was not hinted with a preferred source address. So naturally the host will choose the closest matching address: 172.17.0.1 since it's the primary address on *docker0*. 172.17.0.1 is not in peer's WireGuard's AllowedIPs list (nor should it have to), so will be rejected by WireGuard. If it wasn't rejected, there would be anyway a routing issue in the peer because of the two separate LANs using the same IP address block.

Try this

- System 1

  ```
  ip route replace 192.168.1.0/24 via 172.17.0.5 dev docker0 src 192.168.10.100
  ```
- System 2

  ```
  ip route replace 192.168.10.0/24 via 172.17.0.6 dev docker0 src 192.168.1.100
  ```

Note that before this adjustment, this should not have affected the rest of the LANs, only the two Docker host systems.

Comment: Re explaining what I wrote in the answer: the source address selected was wrong. This route has the src hinted to use the correct source address from the LAN